# Extracting some values from output of an analysis in R

Tags: r

I want to extract some values of an analysis(unit root analysis) into a list(let say list1). However I can't extract the values.

The data is below:

```
> data
 [1]  0.000000000  0.000000000 -0.016800849 -0.005674109 -0.028815092  0.011629070 -0.005805695  0.011561935  0.005739148  0.005690635  0.022474958
[12]  0.038147810 -0.005355004  0.026521835  0.025850717  0.025185460 -0.004994926  0.019804531 -0.014809606  0.004956367 -0.009951292  0.067665001
[23]  0.009303233  0.009217480 -0.018520713 -0.018870213 -0.038843496 -0.009951292  0.058274404  0.063954399  0.043288692  0.081342150  0.015505687
[34] -0.007722791  0.007722791  0.037743885 -0.007435669  0.000000000 -0.007491372 -0.015153238 -0.071171939 -0.041850997 -0.008572604 -0.026204595
[45]  0.026204595  0.042192350 -0.016668594  0.024899845 -0.008231251  0.079403190
```

And the code is like below:

```
library(urca)
adf1<-ur.df(data, type = "drift", lags = 1, selectlags = "BIC")
```

Summary of the analyis is like below:

```
> summary(adf1)

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression drift 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.070631 -0.021526 -0.004443  0.015088  0.072395 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  0.004997   0.004444   1.125  0.26674   
z.lag.1     -0.546913   0.178716  -3.060  0.00372 **
z.diff.lag  -0.173281   0.159606  -1.086  0.28340   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0298 on 45 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3167,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2863 
F-statistic: 10.43 on 2 and 45 DF,  p-value: 0.0001899


Value of test-statistic is: -3.0602 4.7498 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.58 -2.93 -2.60
phi1  7.06  4.86  3.94
```

I want to extract

- "Value of test-statistic" -3.0602 and 4.7498 as 1st argument of list1
- "Multiple R-squared"  0.3167 as the 2nd argument of list1

However, I cant manage to do that. Class of the adf1 seems as below.

```
> class(adf1)
[1] "ur.df"
attr(,"package")
[1] "urca"
```

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
list(teststat = adf1@teststat, r2 = adf1@testreg$r.squared)
```

What I usually do is try to look at the structure of the output using str() and see if the info (like slots) can be accessed using @ or $.